# Google Assistant Hello World Draft Project not updating

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder

Very new to Google Actions. Testing out tutorial stuff.
I have tried this in a couple of test projects just to double check. After initial run of any project I do not get any updates on draft projects. No changes show up in draft projects for me for both simulator and real device.

1. Started new project
2. Even blank project has basic conversation telling you where to add things next.
3. Change text.
4. Notice prompt does not change in testing environment.

In below pictures I have changed the words "hello world" with "Hey Dude" for both fulfillment and console output. I would expect Testing Prompt to respond with "Hey Dude from fulfillment and Hey Dude from the console!" But it does not. Instead it does not reflect any recent changes.

[image: Hey Dude from console]
[image: Hey Dude from Web Hook]
[image: Hello World from console]

Comment: Where is your fulfillment running? From a webhook you run, or through the built-in editor?

Comment: In the example i posted above fulfillment is both a web hook and a response. The web hook is only running in online editor.

Comment: "Fulfillment" meant the code that you're running as a webhook - not the static prompts. That is useful to know, however, that the code from the built-in editor is also not getting deployed correctly on update.

Comment: Fulfillment is running through web hook in app editor. But you are correct that both of the changes are not being picked up. I encountered on a different project. This is the most basic example i could come up with that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Please check the solution on my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68389726/the-test-may-not-have-the-latest-project-changes-try-again-later

Comment: Please find the solution on below post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68389726/the-test-may-not-have-the-latest-project-changes-try-again-later

Comment: Please try the below solution as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68389726/the-test-may-not-have-the-latest-project-changes-try-again-later

Comment: [Google action simulator update issue post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68389726/the-test-may-not-have-the-latest-project-changes-try-again-later)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there may be two slightly different (but sometimes related) issues going on here.

The first is that there are known problems with the simulator being slow to pick up on updates, or them not seeming to show up. The second has to do with making sure you're deploying changes from the build-in code editor.

I don't have a clear answer to the first problem, although I know they're looking into it. I find that I can make some changes and they may not be noticed, but I know they *have* been picked up if I see the "Your preview is being updated..." spinner appear. There are other spinners that sometimes appear, but unless it explicitly says that it is being updated - the updates aren't always picked up. (Sometimes they are, however.)

[image: Your preview is being updated]

Usually, if I don't see this, I'll go back and force an apparent change (delete a character from a webhook handler name, then add it back) and go back to the simulator. In general, this time it will say it is updating.

If you're using the Cloud Functions editor, you need to do three things:

1. Save the changes.  You'll do this by clicking the "Save Fulfillment" button, but this only saves it so you can leave the editor. It doesn't mean that the simulator has access to it yet.

   [image: Save Fulfillment]
2. Deploy the changes. This deploys your code to Cloud Functions so they can be run. Note in the illustration that it says the code is saved, but not yet deployed.

   [image: Deploy Fulfillment]
3. Wait till the changes are fully deployed. Deploying takes time, and until it is completed, it won't be available in the simulator. While deploying, it lets you know.

   [image: Deployment in progress]

   Once it has deployed, however, the message changes, and you the impacts should be available through the simulator (although you may still need to see the "being updated" message to be sure).

   [image: Deployment completed]

Remember, however, that you *don't* need to use the "Cloud Functions editor" in order to deploy a webhook. You can deploy a webhook on any web server where

1. The host is public (so has a public IP address that Google can reach)
2. It can handle HTTPS with a non-self-signed certificate

You can even deploy yourself to Cloud Functions for Firebase, which is the same service that the Actions Builder uses. This way you have the URL set once in the Actions Builder and, once it is set, you won't need to change it.

But you'll still be able to change your code by managing your own deployment separate from Actions Builder.

Comment: Than you for your response. Please don't take this the wrong way, but Argh I have done all of this. I also added an image that shows my webhook successfully deployed and up to date.  I was guessing there might be some update problems so I successfully deployed a couple times last night and woke up this morning to no changes still. 
Again thank you. I will repeat this process again because... sanity.
Is this situation not a problem if deploying using cli and coding it out?
I was looking for a force update or something but did not find it.

Comment: Ok, I think i got it working. This workaround is not sustainable for development. I am not sure what exactly i did in here to fix it.
Steps.
Add exclamation point to text.
Save and Deploy.
Open Test. - Test simulator shows - Updating Preview - returns errors when invoking. Device does not return webhook message
Reset test a couple times. same result
Remove Exclamation point in text. Save and deploy.
Open test simulator. It shows updating preview for a very long time then errors out saying it failed.
Reset Test again. It shows updating preview again and then finally loads correctly.

Comment: I think that my major problem right now is that it seems to require a webhook save and deployment to update the draft. My original project I removed the web hook fulfillment and still had this problem. So any updates to simple conversation in scenes are not updated in draft.

Comment: There isn't a "force update", since it is supposed to update correctly on its own. That's the pending issue. But I've updated my answer to clarify that you don't need to use the Cloud Functions editor - you can deploy and manage the webhook separately.

Comment: is there an actual google issue that can be referenced here?  Because it is pretty much unusable for me right now. I tried to use webhook in cloud functions but it is not picking up that change at all in my original project.

Comment: There are a couple of threads discussing it [on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleAssistantDev/), where I see you've now posted a thread as well. But there is no public issue tracker for the Actions Builder.

Comment: I finally set up the CLI tools. By pulling my project down using `gactions pull --project-id my-project-id` and then immediately calling `gactions deploy preview` I am able to successfully iterate on a project. There are errors. Maybe those errors are holding it up in web console? 
 `gactions deploy preview` is a solid force update.