# The test may not have the latest project changes. Try again later

Tags: actions-on-google

[image: Google Action Test]
While clicking on the test "The test may not have the latest project changes. Try again later." an error is coming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after doing multiple try i am able to resolve it by using following steps.

I found the answers by searching the solution for warning "The test may not have the latest changes.." in action console help.

Pick a display name that is short, unique, and memorable. Your brand or product name is usually a good choice. This name is used as the way users invoke your Action, and it serves as the title of your listing in the Assistant directory.

Caution: If you have multiple Actions projects that use the same display name, the simulator chooses one at random. For consistent testing results, use unique names or release channels for each Action.

Reference Link: https://support.google.com/actions-console/answer/9613473?hl=en

Now how to give display name or change display name.

Go to develop tab and give display name or change display name as follows

[image: Goole Action Develope tab]

Answer (score 2):

Go to the "Develop" tab and change the Display Name.

So, while testing you will be saying "Talk to " rather than "Talk to my test app"